# PyQt5 custom QAction class

Tags: python, c++, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

In an effort to reduce clutter. I am trying to produce my own class that inherits from `QAction`. From a `QMainWindow` I want to call reproduce the following code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.quit)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
```

As you can see I am simply adding an action to a menubar. But I would like to make my program more object oriented. I would hope the following is possible:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class exitAction(QAction):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super.__init__(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', parent)
        self.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.triggered.connect(parent.quit)
```

Where the `exitAction` class is called via the following:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):

        #Create Menu
        self.menuBar = self.menuBar()

        #Add File Menu
        file_menu = self.menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        file_menu.addAction(exitAction(self))
```

This seems simple enough but what doesn't make sense to me is why the near-equivalent code works fine on its own.

The error I get is `TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'QIcon'`. The problem I've set myself up with might be a python misunderstanding as well. If I were working in C++ I would simply pass a pointer that references the MainWindow.

Comment: As an aside, you might look into using keyword arguments when constructing the action instead of subclassing `QAction` over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your problem here:

```
super.__init__(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', parent)
```

you should write `super().` not `super.`

Comment: wow what a silly mistake. Thank you. Atleast I know the code can be written in an object oriented manner.